# I am getting Keras import error when using Keras g;pu 2.2.4 version

Tags: import, keras, runtime-error

I get and keras import error for the following statement when I run the following code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.models'
```

It should be noted that i get this error only with Tensor flow GPU version 1.12 and Keras GPU 2.2.4. I do not get this error when running on Tensor flow GPU version 1.3.0 and keras GPU 2.08. Would appreciate how to fix this issue and why I am getting this error.

Comment: There is no official package called keras gpu, you should install the official package via pip, it works.

Comment: Can you please fix this to use Markdown formatting w/ a code-block for the code and comment block for the error message?

Comment: Do you have a file in your directory called keras.py? If so, that will block access to the actual keras module.

Comment: You state that the error is in TensorFlow v.1.12.0.  In TensorFlow, we use `from tensorflow import keras` to import the Keras module.